# Could we use global variables/objects in Apache Storm

Tags: java, apache-storm

In apache storm, if we want to pass variables from one bolt to next bolt, we should use `emit` function in previous bolt's `execute()` method.

However, is it possible use global variables that each bolt can see. For example, there is a map object, some bolts update the map, some bolt get value from it.

Comment: its advisable not to use global variables for inter-bolt communication, its best to use a clusterable cache or emit the new data with a specific key.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I want to know why it is not advisable to use global variables for inter-bolt communication? Any thing to concern? Does it mean global variables is possible but not best practice? Many thanks!

Comment: when you deploy a storm application, it can run on multiple machines, which means that if 2 bolts exist and one adds an entry into the map, it wont get carried to the 2nd one, and it might (and very probably) malfunction. leading developers chasing ghosts.

Comment: So if there are two bolts in different machine, it is impossible using global parameters to cross machine. What we can do are only clusterable cache and emit function?

Comment: this might help .. https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Concepts.html

Comment: each bolt get own copy of global object, if you declare. they are not shared with other instance of bolts. use some persistence medium for such things.